Angular 17 - Does subscribing to FormControl's valueChanges need an unsubscribe?
The answers in this topic are older than 7 years. Is it state of the art that I need unsubscribe FormControl subscription from ReactiveFormsModule?
formControl = new FormControl("default", {nonNullable: true});

ngOnInit(){
  this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    ...
  });   
}

Using takeUntilDestroyed in a ssr-project, then it throws some build errors:
⠹ Building...
ERROR _ [Error]: NG0203
    at sl (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/81fd9210-872c-4b96-8341-24ec7fdb69e6/chunk-NL545L5S.mjs:7:13224)
    at Li (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/81fd9210-872c-4b96-8341-24ec7fdb69e6/chunk-QXK5UEHF.mjs:5:110180)
    at e.ngOnInit (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/81fd9210-872c-4b96-8341-24ec7fdb69e6/chunk-QXK5UEHF.mjs:5:112025)
    ...
    at Vd (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/81fd9210-872c-4b96-8341-24ec7fdb69e6/chunk-NL545L5S.mjs:7:58146) {
  code: -203
⠙ Building...
ERROR _ [Error]: NG0203
    at sl (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/6a2048f8-a61c-4e69-8230-6585a5b96a65/chunk-NL545L5S.mjs:7:13224)
    at Li (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/6a2048f8-a61c-4e69-8230-6585a5b96a65/chunk-QXK5UEHF.mjs:5:110180)
    at e.ngOnInit (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/6a2048f8-a61c-4e69-8230-6585a5b96a65/chunk-QXK5UEHF.mjs:5:112025)
    ...
  code: -203
⠙ Building...
ERROR _ [Error]: NG0203
    at sl (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/05e20dd1-bcbb-410a-8229-f5c7e6bd5445/chunk-NL545L5S.mjs:7:13224)
    ...    
  code: -203
⠼ Building...
ERROR _ [Error]: NG0203
    at sl (file:///project/path/.angular/prerender-root/071e7b24-587d-43a7-bab9-26fa2afede39/chunk-NL545L5S.mjs:7:13224)
    ...
  code: -203

Can I ignore them because the build is not interrupted and the result is executable?

Did you see the takeUntilDestroyed rxjs operator. It simplifies unsubscribing from observables

@Pieterjan, got some build errors using takeUntilDestroyed within ssr-project. Can I ignore them?

Quick answer:
YES, cause it is an infinite observable
Here is a good article for an in-depth explanation:
 FINITE vs INFINITE observables
Explanation:
So the question boils down to Finite vs Infinite observables:
If you don't know when it is to stop emitting values in the foreseeable future of component lifecycle then it should be unsubscribed in the OnDestroy hook to prevent memory leaks
eg: fromEvent(document, 'click') or valueChange from formControl in your case
But if you think that observable is gonna emit a specific set of values ( Finite observable ), then:

If there is a chance that the component might get destroyed before the observable emits all of its values then adding an unsub logic should be considered.
eg: fromEvent(document, 'click') or valueChange from formControl in your case

If it's sure that the observable will emit all of its values before the component is destroyed, we don't need to worry about unsubscribing it
eg: httpClient or of([1,2,3]), both are gonna emit specific set of values and complete




Yes, you do. Note that you do not need to unsubscribe from http calls
because they auto-complete themselves.

You must unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks and to avoid unexpected
side-effects in your application.


